# Parse JSON in java does not work

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON `{"id":"279537","valuation":857}` saved in a `String` variable named `result`.

```
String result = "{\"id\":\"279537\",\"valuation\":857}";
```

This JSON is the result of a server response. I want to parse the JSON and save `id` and `valuation` properties into variables and then print the values on screen.

Here is the code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
int id = obj.getInt("id");
int valuation = obj.getInt("valuation");
System.out.println(id);
System.out.println(valuation);
```

Unfortunately, nothing is printed on screen.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem which suggests that problem is in part which you are not showing us. Post *short* but *full* code which will let us reproduce it (in other words create and post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) / [MCVE]).

Comment: That still is not enough to simply copy-paste your code and reproduce this problem. We don't even know from which library/package `JSONObject` comes from. Please take your time and create short but *full* example.

Comment: Probably. Unfortunately I am not JEE expert so I can't help you much. But still I would advise to add proper tags your question with tools you are using (like `jsf`) so experts observing these tags would be informed about your question, and limit your code to only necessary parts (does your bean really need every property here?)

Comment: Yes. All properties are used in the xhtml file. In another part which is not relevant with the problem I face.

Comment: That is what I am saying, if they are not important for this problem then you don't need them in this question. I strongly encourage you to creating from scratch short and simple example which will let us reproduce your problem. There is even high chance that you will find cause of your problem while creating such example.

Answer (score -1):

This is not working:

```
id = obj.getInt("id");
```

**your id is a string** note that is between qoutes...

do instead:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
String id = obj.getString("id");
int valuation = obj.getInt("valuation");
System.out.println(id);
System.out.println(valuation);
```

Comment: In that case OP would get some exception which is not the problem here.

Comment: how are you sure the OP is not getting an exception... the code is not complete...

Comment: "...but *nothing* is printed on screen" (emphasis mine)

Comment: I do not get any exception. I have laready tried to declare the id as String, but it did not work. I want id and valuation to be global.